# Wifi connectivity

Tags: boot, networking, usb, xubuntu

Steps before problem occurs:

1. I completely removed gnome-desktop
2. Installed xubuntu-desktop
3. Then ran sudo apt remove xubuntu-desktop^
4. Nothing left
5. Reboot.

Booting Stuck on dev/sda clean ..

6. Alt+f2
   Logged in.
   Now my system has no necessary packages.
   Problem:
   I can't connect to WiFi since network-manager not installed
   I created ubuntu bootable pendrive using dd,but that also didn't work because firmware not showing bootable USB
   What to do

Answer (score 0):

Download network-manger and its dependencies manually.
Install using dpkg.
Connect to wifi using nmcli
Done!!